# Php make a complete table row to a link?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, html-table

I am trying to make a imap mail client and I made a function to list all folders inside a table. However I made the names of them to links to navigate through them. This is all good but I want to click anywhere in the row to go to that link. I saw some Javascripts but I don't know how to put them inside my for loop. Here is the code from it:

```
echo "<table align='left' border='1' class='Mailtable' style='width:10%;'><tr><td style='width:9%;'>Ordner</td></tr>";      
$boxes = imap_list($mbox, "{".$host."}", '*');
$boxescount = count($boxes);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $boxescount-1; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    $boxes[$i]=str_replace($host,"",$boxes[$i]);
    $boxes[$i]=str_replace("{}","",$boxes[$i]);
    $boxes[$i]=str_replace("&APw-","ü",$boxes[$i]);
    $boxes[$i]=str_replace("&APY-","ö",$boxes[$i]);
    $l=str_replace("[Gmail]/","",$boxes[$i]);
    $boxes[$i]= "<a href='mail.php?v=".$boxes[$i]."'>".$l."</a>";
    echo $boxes[$i];

    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: `echo "<tr onclick=\"myJsFunction(".$i.")\"><td>";` or if you have JQuery, you may select the tr and asign a .click function `.click(function(tihs) {...})`

Comment: As I see it, you have in the end a `tr` element with a single `td` containing a single `a` tag, right? In this case just give it with css `display: block;` that should do the trick.

Comment: i cant get this to work with these solutions should something pop up when i hover over the rows? like when i hover over a normal link? when yes this dont happen to me.